# Django - Change model field in script and migrate

Tags: python, django

I am creating a Django project where I have a field that automatically generates random ids. I want to start with `max_length = 1` and increase it everytime there are no more unique ids left. For example: I use `string.ascii_letters + string.digits + ["$-_+"]` for random ids. With `max_length = 1` there are 66 unique ids left. When I have created the 66. object, `max_length` should be updated to `2` and my database should be migrated. Now I have `66^2 - 66` ids left.

Here's what I tried:

```
class RandomIDMixin(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=settings.DATABASE_ID_MAX_LENGTH, editable=False, primary_key=True, verbose_name="ID", unique=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

@receiver(pre_save)
def pre_saver(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if issubclass(sender, RandomIDMixin):
        choices = random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + ["$-_+"])
        max_length = instance._meta.get_field('id').max_length

        if instance.id is None or instance.id is "":
            while sender.objects.filter(id=instance.id).exists() or instance.id is None or instance.id is "":
                instance.id = "".join(choices, k=max_length)
```

Comment: why you do it? may be uuid will be better solution?

Comment: and `max_length = instance._meta.get_field('id').max_length` will always equal `settings.DATABASE_ID_MAX_LENGTH`

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to change the db column length. You should get that to a sensible value to start with and apply the length validation in Django code.

Comment: You have to pass `max_length` in `models.CharField` itself at object creation time (when application starts) because databases impose very static data structures. I don't know why would you do that it is a very strange idea overall. If your concerns are memory, django uses `varchar` behind the scenes which occupy only as much space as needed. Just specify a moderate (64 is enough) `max_langth` and let things run.